# Servlet request.getParameter() always return null value

Tags: java, servlets

I'm working on simple client server communication using HttpPost. From the client side I'm setting a parameter(filename).

At the server side when I try to get the parameter value it's always showing **null**. I tried using **MultiPartEntity** but even that is not working.

Below is my client code:

```java
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy");
            InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                    new FileInputStream(dataFile), -1);
            reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");

            // Send in multiple parts if needed
            reqEntity.setChunked(true);
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            //setting the parameter
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("filename", "xxxx.xml");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int respcode =  response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

And this is my servlet code:

```java
    response.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());

    // reading the parameter
    String filename = request.getParameter("filename");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\" + filename)));
```

Kindly let me know any possible solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Ur setting parameters wrong... at the client side, do this:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename", "xxxx.xml");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already I'm setting a reqEntity, httppost.setEntity(reqEntity); If I follow your logic now I'm not getting source data writing in the file. Is it possible to set multiple entities?

Comment: U can achieve this it two requests. First set and execute file name as mentioned above in answer. Receive it in the servlet before reading input stream and in the second request send ur stream